# What is the proper way to have a Windows service stop and start gracefully when suspending/resuming a PC?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, power-state

I need to stop our Windows service when a PC is powered down into Suspend mode and restart it when the PC is resumed again. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: So why not rephrase your question to *"Why can I not override OnPowerEvent?"*  This is clearly the preferred mechanism for dealing with the situation.

Comment: I figured out why I couldn't override it, I'm an idiot and made the return type void... hahaha. Guess I can edit this question and still make it useful

Comment: So, that's the way to go.

Comment: Always type `override` and then use code completion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should override the [ServiceBase.OnPowerEvent Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onpowerevent.aspx).

```
protected override bool OnPowerEvent(PowerBroadcastStatus powerStatus)
{
    if (powerStatus.HasFlag(PowerBroadcastStatus.QuerySuspend))
    { 

    }

    if (powerStatus.HasFlag(PowerBroadcastStatus.ResumeSuspend))
    {

    }
    return base.OnPowerEvent(powerStatus);
}
```

The [PowerBroadcastStatus Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.powerbroadcaststatus.aspx) explains the power statuses.
Also, you'll need to set the [ServiceBase.CanHandlePowerEvent Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canhandlepowerevent.aspx) to `true`.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
}
```

Comment: Set CanHandlePowerEvent in service constructor - Cannot change CanStop, CanPauseAndContinue, CanShutdown, CanHandlePowerEvent, or CanHandleSessionChangeEvent property values after the service has been started.

Comment: Any reason you check the enum with HasFlag, according to this http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceProcess/System/ServiceProcess/PowerBroadcastStatus.cs it isnt marked with flag?

Comment: Using HasFlag() here is definitely wrong! Look into the enum values of PowerBroadcastStatus to see it's not at all suitable as a bit mask.

Answer (score 3):

Comment on Alex Filipovici Answer edited May 16 '13 at 17:05:

```
CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
```

must be set in the constructor

Setting it in `OnStart()` is too late and causes this Exception:

```
Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot change CanStop, CanPauseAndContinue,     CanShutdown, CanHandlePowerEvent, or CanHandleSessionChangeEvent property values after the service has been started.
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.set_CanHandlePowerEvent(Boolean value)
   at foo.bar.OnStart(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the features of Windows service.

#### Shutdown

The shutdown is done automatically when PC is shut down. No need to do anything. To do any clean up you would need to override `ServiceBase` type methods like [`OnPowerEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onpowerevent.aspx), sample

```
public class WinService : ServiceBase
{
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override bool OnPowerEvent(PowerBroadcastStatus powerStatus)
    {
            ...
    }
}
```

#### Start

To start a service automatically you need to set it to [`ServiceStartMode.Automatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicestartmode.aspx) like here

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class WindowsServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    private readonly ServiceProcessInstaller _process;
    private readonly ServiceInstaller _service;

    public WindowsServiceInstaller()
    {
        _process = new ServiceProcessInstaller
        {
            Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem
        };
        _service = new ServiceInstaller
        {
            ServiceName = "FOO",
            StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic, // <<<HERE
            Description = "Foo service"
        };
        Installers.Add(_process);
        Installers.Add(_service);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well we have things to do in the event of a shutdown, so we have to perform those first, then call base.OnShutdown(), base.OnStop(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stopping your service could you simply stop the processing with something like...

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += this.SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;

    private void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Suspend)
            {

            }

        if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Resume)
            {

            }
    }
```

Comment: Note that if you do this you'll need to make sure that the suspend doesn't take too long because the time granted by the service control manager during a regular overload of OnPowerEvent suspend might not be granted here.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: The event handlers probably get called synchronously from inside `OnPowerEvent`, so I don't think the behavior will be different.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I didn't notice that this event wasn't being provided by `ServiceBase`.

Comment: This code needs a Window running. That might be not what you want in a Windows Service.